# TeamCity is running the same test twice, after the test was moved to a different package

Tags: java, eclipse, teamcity

So my issue is the same as the title. I have TeamCity v. 8.0.3 (build 27540), and have several test packs set in place. The issue is that I wrote a test in Eclipse, moved it to another package, and now every time that the test build kicks off in TC it runs that test two times, once for the original package(even though it's not there anymore), and once for the new package.

I haven't seen this happening for any test before, and would like to know if anyone encountered this situation and if they have a solution.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely files left from the previous build. If you enable [Swabra](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Files+Cleaner+%28Swabra%29) it will clean such files automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to clean your project - the old `.class` files are likely to be hanging around. If you're using maven, change the invocation to include the `clean` phase. Make sure you didn't accidentally check in the `.class` files, too.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! However, the Swabra solution seemed a little faster and less of a headache. Regardless, thank you!